# C++ Simple entity component

Tags: c++, design-patterns, components

I want to create a very simple enemy class that gets attributes from components rather than inheritance. Attributes will be just health i guess for now. I need an example really simple one to start with. Still learning about the component pattern and i am lost still.

Any help would be incredible!

Comment: What kind of "component" do you have in mind? There's no such language construct in C++. Where did you get the term from (i.e. what is a component for you, what's your definition?), what intention would you have behind using them?

Comment: Game objects that receive attributes (damage, health, flammability, etc.) from component objects rather than inheritance.

That is what i am told to create... so not entirely sure. But i want one as simple that it only has health

Comment: what is a "component object" supposed to be? maybe it would help if you would given an example how you would solve the problem at hand with inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you would want to use composition.  In this case define your classes something like:

Health component:

```
class Health
{
public:
    Health();
    // other attributes / methods defined here
};
```

Skills component:

```
class Skills
{
public:
    Skills();
    // other attributes / methods defined here
};
```

Weapons component:

```
class Weapons
{
public:
    Weapons();
    // other attributes / methods defined here
};
```

The Enemy class is then defined by composition from other components:

```
#include "health.h"
#include "weapons.h"
#include "skills.h"
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();

    Health itsHealth;
    Weapons itsWeapons;
    Skills itsSkills;
};
```

where the "example" components that I came up with are defined in separate classes as shown.  Each class then keeps track of its own instance variables and methods.

Your Enemy class constructor then determines how each of the components are defined when an enemy object is created.  You might also take a look at class initializer lists for examples on how to setup these components with default values.

Comment: This looks pretty good. But not sure what do the constructors do? Sorry i am still a first year student.

Comment: Constructors will recieve instances of `Helth`, `Weapons` and `Skils` (one of each) and initialize the attributes...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to go about it, do you want an ECS Architecture, where you have entities, relying on components, and systems updating the entities and component. 
I usually will say each component contains:

1.an id (whether it be a string or int)

2.a vector of components

3.an entity of a parent, if null, this is a root

4.a vector of entities as children.

There will be systems for basically each component, or component type. like graphics will have a stack of images to load into a buffer to display, or a physics system that performs updates on gravity inside the world, and the change of movement (delta).